# agregar productos y guardar elementos de la tabla generada en una matriz para enviar a una API

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo una peticion get a una api que me muestra una lista de productos. pero solo logre hacer para un medicamento, como puedo agregar mas medicamentos a la tabla? sin que se refresque la pagina tengo el siguiente código de Jquery:
para buscar el producto:

```js
$('#agregaMedicamento').on('click', function(e){

      e.preventDefault();

      var codigo = $('#datecodigo').val();
      var cantidad = $('#datecantidad').val();
      var requestUrl = '/medicamento/' + codigo;

      $.ajax({
        url: requestUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(medicamento){
          var tbody = $('tbody#tbody3');
          tbody.html('');

          var obj = medicamento;

          obj.medicamento.forEach(function(elemento,indice){
            tbody.append(`
              <tr>
                <td class="codigo">${elemento.codigo}</td>
                <td class="nombre">${elemento.nombre}</td>
                <td class="cantidad">${cantidad}</td>
                <td class="precio">${elemento.precio}</td>
                <td class="importe">${elemento.precio * cantidad}</td>
              </tr>
            `)
          });
        }
      });
  });
```

Pero esa peticion solo me muestra un medicamento y no tengo idea como agregar un producto mas a la tabla generada:

[image: La peticion me muestra la tabla de abajo]

Al agregar mas productos tengo que enviar los datos en formato json dentro de una matriz pero no logro hacer eso. soy nuevo en javascript.